# Mounting old windows 98 share

Tags: mount, windows, raspberry-pi, cifs

I have a Raspberry Pi directly connected to a Windows 98 machine with a crossover Ethernet cable. I have made a shared directory on the Windows 98 machine (completely open).  The problem arises when I try to mount the shared folder on the RPi.

The commands I have tried are as follows:

1. ```sh
   sudo mount.cifs //<ip-adress>/share /mount/directory -o port=#
   ```
2. ```sh
   sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //<ip-adress>/share /mount/directory
   ```
3. ```sh
   sudo mount -t cifs -o port=# //<ip-adress>/share /mount/directory
   ```

All of these give me the same error: "Host is down".

I can ping the windows 98 from the Pi and vice versa; a `nmap` scan also shows that the two can talk together.

If I open the file manager, I can access the shares:

[image]

And from there I can create and delete folders, files etc.
The problem, however, is that I need to be able to access the share using a path to run my backup script.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, found the solution on [Mounting a Windows 98  computer's SMB share  in Linux](https://www.downtowndougbrown.com/2018/02/mounting-a-windows-98-computers-smb-share-in-linux/). The the critical part is following:

> servern=MYSERVER
>
> This option specifies that the name of the server you are connecting to is MYSERVER. You have to specify the name of the server you’re trying to connect to if you try to mount a Windows 98 share, or else it won’t work. So this option is super important.

Unlike the website recommends, using `guest` option did not work for me, instead I used `username=guest`, but it seems any user name will do.

The complete command I succeeded with on Debian 10 was:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=guest,password=****,vers=1.0,servern=MYSERVER //<ip-address>/share /mnt/directory
```

**Edit:**
I have noticed, that the share works for read-only access only. Writing to it will fail and output message:

> CIFS VFS: bogus file nlink value 0

But since you wrote, that it's for a backup script, that should not matter much.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting such error because when browsing from the file manager you're actually using smbclient, which works fine on old smb version. Unfortunately smbfs and the smbmount command, which were working fine, have been deprecated and replaced by cifs and its mount.cifs, which don't work at all with older shares. I'm on the same boat and haven't found a solution so far, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I solved an issue how to connect old Windows 98 to Ubuntu/Debian using mount.cifs (in my case my system is Raspbian), working command is:

sudo mount -t cifs -o user=guest,pass=,vers=1.0,sec=none,domain=MOSSBAUERLAB,ip=192.168.10.217,servern=MICHAEL //MICHAEL/AUTOSAVES /mnt/sm2201/dev
Where:

MICHAEL is my computer name
AUTOSAVES name of shared folder
MOSSBAERLAB is a Workgroup name
There are one significant thing that should be Noted, all names (Computer, Workgroup, Share) must be in uppercase.